# Make a Yin-Yang circle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I've been trying to attempt a Yin-Yang circle on Python, but so far I've only been able to do a black semi-circle. In here I've attached what it looks like for me and what it's supposed to look like. What else should I add to my code? 
*to make it easier for me to understand, use fill function when coloring.

My Code:

```
import turtle

turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(50,180)
turtle.end_fill()
turtle.hideturtle()
```

What it looks like for me:
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OWl6.png)

How it's supposed to be:
[desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3YWh.png)

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; **asking us to write the program** for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I like @CameronFerguson's single curve approach (+1), it might be easier for a beginner to think of this as simply five circles.  The first, largest circle is filled on one side, as you have already achieved.  The next two circles are half the radius of the original, centered on the vertical axis, and opposite colored:

[image]

Choose a size for the smallest two circles, above they are 1/8th of the original radius, use the same center point as the previous circles and reverse the color again.  Now, switching to the final colors, and raising the pen appropriately to avoid unwanted lines, we get:

[image]

With some additional thought, the two sets of inner circles can done in a loop, cutting the number of calls to `turtle.circle()` in half.  But if you're comfortable with @CameronFerguson's curve approach, go with that!

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty close already, if you think of the yin-yang symbol mathematically, it's just a bunch of arcs, two large ones on the outside, and two on the inside, half the length.
If the outside arcs have a length of 50, then the internal arcs need to be 25. Turtles move counter-clockwise by default, so to get a clockwise curve, use a negative radius. Like so:

```
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(50, 180)
turtle.circle(25, 180)
turtle.circle(-25, 180)
turtle.end_fill()
turtle.circle(-50, 180)
```

After that, the turtle will back where it started, and the positions for the circles should be roughly a quarter and three quarters of 50 directly below the turtle, where you just need to make two full circles.

Comment: what r the points for the circle?

Comment: I'm sorry, which points are you referring to?